# Different breaks per facet in ggplot2 histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

A ggplot2-challenged latticist needs help: What's the syntax to request variable per-facet breaks in a histogram?

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x=c(rnorm(100,10,0.1),rnorm(100,20,0.1)),par=rep(letters[1:2],each=100))
# Note: breaks have different length by par
breaks = list(a=seq(9,11,by=0.1),b=seq(19,21,by=0.2))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x) ) + 
  geom_histogram() + ### Here the ~breaks should be added
  facet_wrap(~ par,  scales="free")
```

As pointed out by [jucor](https://github.com/xfim/ggmcmc/pull/17#issuecomment-19899183), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/rhPWQEFMx6A) some more solutions.

On special request, and to show why I am not a great ggplot fan, the `lattice` version

```
library(lattice)
d = data.frame(x=c(rnorm(100,10,0.1),rnorm(100,20,0.1)),par=rep(letters[1:2],each=100))
# Note: breaks have different length by par
myBreaks = list(a=seq(8,12,by=0.1),b=seq(18,22,by=0.2))
histogram(~x|par,data=d,
          panel = function(x,breaks,...){
            # I don't know of a generic way to get the 
            # grouping variable with histogram, so 
            # this is not very generic
            par = levels(d$par)[which.packet()]
            breaks = myBreaks[[par]]
            panel.histogram(x,breaks=breaks,...)
          },
          breaks=NULL, # important to force per-panel compute
          scales=list(x=list(relation="free")))
```

[image]

Comment: As a latticist defender ..can you share please the lattice version..

Comment: You could do the binning outside of ggplot2, e.g. using `hist` in combination with `ddply` or `data.table` or ..., and make barplots.

Comment: Yes, that looks like the method to go. Since this is for a package of another author, it would required some work. https://github.com/xfim/ggmcmc/pull/17

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is one alternative:

```
hls <- mapply(function(x, b) geom_histogram(data = x, breaks = b), 
              dlply(d, .(par)), myBreaks)
ggplot(d, aes(x=x)) + hls + facet_wrap(~par, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

If you need to shrink the range of x, then

```
hls <- mapply(function(x, b) {
  rng <- range(x$x)
  bb <- c(rng[1], b[rng[1] <= b & b <= rng[2]], rng[2])
  geom_histogram(data = x, breaks = bb, colour = "white")
}, dlply(d, .(par)), myBreaks)

ggplot(d, aes(x=x)) + hls + facet_wrap(~par, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: The Master strikes again. Nevertheless: the lattice solution, if not perfect, is much more transparent.

Comment: nice approach. thank you. unfortunately it does not help to apply different binwidth as scaling factor for a density curve... geom_density(data = x, aes(y = binwidth * ..count..))

Comment: Can you explain what is going on inside that first `mapply`?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that it is possible to give different break points in each facet.

As workaround you can make two plots and then with `grid.arrange()` function from library `gridExtra` put them together. To set break points in `geom_histogram()` use `binwidth=` and set one value for width of bin.

```
p1<-ggplot(subset(d,par=="a"), aes(x=x) ) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1) +
  facet_wrap(~ par)

p2<-ggplot(subset(d,par=="b"), aes(x=x) ) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.2) +
  facet_wrap(~ par)
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will accept that later if there is no alternative (which I fear). However, for the real job I have some hundreds of histogram for Bayes plots, so it gets messy: see https://github.com/xfim/ggmcmc/pull/17.

Answer (score 4):

Following on from Didzis example:

```
ggplot(dat=d, aes(x=x, y=..ncount..)) +
  geom_histogram(data = d[d$par == "a",], binwidth=0.1) +
  geom_histogram(data = d[d$par == "b",], binwidth=0.01) +  
  facet_grid(.~ par, scales="free")
```

EDIT: This works for more levels but of course there are already better solutions

```
# More facets
d <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(200,10,0.1),rnorm(200,20,0.1)),par=rep(letters[1:4],each=100))

# vector of binwidths same length as number of facets - need a nicer way to calculate these
my.width=c(0.5,0.25,0.1,0.01)

out<-lapply(1:length(my.width),function(.i) data.frame(par=levels(d$par)[.i],ggplot2:::bin(d$x[d$par==levels(d$par)[.i]],binwidth=my.width[.i])))

my.df<-do.call(rbind , out)

ggplot(my.df) + geom_histogram(aes(x, y = density, width = width), stat =  "identity") + facet_wrap(~par,scales="free")
```

from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/ggplot2/bin$20histogram$20by$20facet/ggplot2/xlqRIFPP-zE/CgfigIkgAAkJ

Comment: This works for the example, but is not easily generalizable to the 100+ cases from a Bayesian estimation.

Answer (score 3):

It is not, strictly speaking, possible to give different breaks in the different facets. But you can get the same effect by having a different layer for each facet (much as in [user20650's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17286116/892313)), but mostly automating the multiple `geom_histogram` calls:

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(100,10,0.1),rnorm(100,20,0.1)),
                par=rep(letters[1:2],each=100))
breaks <- list(a=seq(9,11,by=0.1),b=seq(19,21,by=0.2))

ggplot(d, aes(x=x)) +
  mapply(function(d, b) {geom_histogram(data=d, breaks=b)}, 
         split(d, d$par), breaks) +
  facet_wrap(~ par,  scales="free_x")
```

[image]

The `mapply` call creates a list of `geom_histogram`s which can be added to the plot. The tricky part is that you have to manually split the data (`split(d, d$par)`) into the data that goes into each facet.