# Changing the breaks and limits in a facet_grid where scales="free_y"

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

Is possible to control separately the `limits` and the `breaks` of a given axis (`x` of `y`) when the `facet_grid` uses the `scales="free_smth" parameter?

I have a plot where I have used `facet_grid(scales="free_y") because the faceted data are of different orders of magnitude.

Now I would like to control separately the limit of the y axis for each of those grids: for example make each of the y axis 10% longer?

Is there a way to achieve that? For the breaks I found this post: [Change the number of breaks using facet_grid in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436855/change-the-number-of-breaks-using-facet-grid-in-ggplot2)

---

**dput(mod)**

```
structure(list(clusteringDistance = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), value = c(0.00010666666666667, 
9.2e-05, 0.00026716666666667, 0.0013231666666667, 0.0010328333333333, 
0.0011373333333333, 0.00098416666666667, 0.0010616666666667, 
0.0010146666666667, 0.0012793333333333, 0.0010886666666667, 0.0011816666666667, 
0.001202, 0.00018966666666667, 0.0012435, 0.0012611666666667, 
0.0012225, 0.0014066666666667, 0.0011566666666667, 0.0011533333333333, 
0.001219, 0.0013335, 0.001161, 0.0011793333333333, 0.00020816666666667, 
0.001246, 0.0012645, 0.0012855, 0.0011951666666667, 0.0012993333333333, 
0.0012543333333333, 0.001277, 0.0012546666666667, 0.0012316666666667, 
0.0012323333333333, 0.00027716666666667, 0.0012656666666667, 
0.0012198333333333, 0.0012871666666667, 0.0012713333333333, 0.0012286666666667, 
0.0013265, 0.0012663333333333, 0.0012253333333333, 0.0012365, 
0.0012658333333333, 0.001131, 0.0012593333333333, 0.0011905, 
0.0012405, 0.001185, 0.0012011666666667, 0.0013628333333333, 
0.0012721666666667, 0.0012106666666667, 0.0012755, 0.000267, 
0.0012025, 0.0012623333333333, 0.0011698333333333, 0.0012455, 
0.0012586666666667, 0.0011565, 0.0012275, 0.0012603333333333, 
0.001187, 0.0011595, 0.000209, 0.0011738333333333, 0.0011486666666667, 
0.001163, 0.001153, 0.0011851666666667, 0.001198, 0.0011925, 
0.0012245, 0.0012425, 0.0012261666666667, 0.0012, 0.0012836666666667, 
0.0012158333333333, 0.001177, 0.0012495, 0.0011931666666667, 
0.001234, 0.0012195, 0.0012295, 0.0012155, 0.00015716666666667, 
0.0012991666666667, 0.0012633333333333, 0.0012423333333333, 0.001199, 
0.0011716666666667, 0.0012826666666667, 0.0012528333333333, 0.0011571666666667, 
0.0012435, 0.0012781666666667, 0.0013143333333333, 0.0011633333333333, 
0.0011976666666667, 0.001196, 0.0011395, 0.0011865, 0.001147, 
0.0012036666666667, 0.0011896666666667, 0.00124, 7.4666666666667e-05, 
0.00025516666666667, 0.0012921666666667, 0.0012025, 0.0011845, 
0.0011926666666667, 0.0013056666666667, 0.0011756666666667, 0.0012155, 
0.0012035, 0.0012886666666667, 0.0011025, 0.00026633333333333, 
0.0012688333333333, 0.0012365, 0.0011651666666667, 0.001195, 
0.001265, 0.0012431666666667, 0.0013061666666667, 0.0011521666666667, 
0.0012096666666667, 0.00032483333333333, 0.00031, 0.00040233333333333, 
0.00032033333333333, 0.0002915, 0.00042983333333333, 0.00029833333333333, 
0.00028616666666667, 0.00051583333333333, 0.00041666666666667, 
0.00041466666666667, 0.00040816666666667, 0.00046783333333333, 
0.0003555, 0.0003485, 0.0005515, 6.7e-05, 0.00057783333333333, 
0.00048833333333333, 0.000453, 0.00047483333333333, 0.0005075, 
0.00035433333333333, 0.00051033333333333, 4e-04, 0.00036266666666667, 
0.0004625, 0.00061383333333333, 0.000664, 0.00062183333333333, 
0.0005585, 0.00055116666666667, 0.0006355, 0.000604, 0.00074483333333333, 
0.00055533333333333, 0.00051866666666667, 7.9333333333333e-05, 
0.00076566666666667, 0.000814, 0.00070183333333333, 0.00064633333333333, 
0.000646, 0.00065583333333333, 0.00068283333333333, 0.000662, 
0.000764, 9.7333333333333e-05, 0.00088266666666667, 0.00082033333333333, 
0.00086933333333333, 0.00074833333333333, 0.00084566666666667, 
0.00085483333333333, 0.00081883333333333, 0.00071416666666667, 
0.00091366666666667, 0.00094916666666667, 0.0009515, 0.00090083333333333, 
0.00083716666666667, 0.00087516666666667, 0.00092616666666667, 
0.0009725, 0.0009595, 0.0008025, 0.0010385, 0.00091266666666667, 
7.85e-05, 0.001046, 0.001037, 0.0010123333333333, 0.0010641666666667, 
0.0010223333333333, 0.0010121666666667, 0.0009605, 0.0010576666666667, 
0.0010251666666667, 0.0080813333333332, 0.013676666666666, 0.030540666666667, 
0.13544366666668, 0.11303933333335, 0.14128766666668, 0.12586283333335, 
0.12668700000001, 0.11473816666668, 0.12948183333335, 0.12783083333335, 
0.14297133333335, 0.12485666666668, 0.022364166666667, 0.15427833333335, 
0.14865350000002, 0.14814016666668, 0.15714416666668, 0.12340850000001, 
0.15139016666668, 0.15003233333335, 0.13678033333335, 0.14764633333334, 
0.15059450000001, 0.024483666666667, 0.16980650000001, 0.15460516666668, 
0.14597833333334, 0.12947866666668, 0.14962866666668, 0.17538850000001, 
0.16767900000001, 0.16347166666668, 0.15681133333335, 0.16668333333335, 
0.027774666666668, 0.14393200000001, 0.17449083333335, 0.16182283333335, 
0.16528333333335, 0.16019383333335, 0.16976633333335, 0.15777716666668, 
0.15072316666668, 0.16323216666668, 0.16992333333335, 0.17683200000001, 
0.17644600000001, 0.18862233333335, 0.16511600000001, 0.18438866666668, 
0.17252183333335, 0.16145350000001, 0.16844166666668, 0.16283783333335, 
0.15681850000001, 0.023745833333333, 0.18815700000001, 0.19959000000002, 
0.19608483333335, 0.18081316666668, 0.17618400000001, 0.17062400000002, 
0.21095966666668, 0.19133783333335, 0.17609500000002, 0.17706733333335, 
0.028174000000001, 0.19673900000001, 0.17761916666668, 0.21074966666668, 
0.18421533333335, 0.17826033333335, 0.18994016666668, 0.20208450000001, 
0.19693450000001, 0.17956533333335, 0.17582466666668, 0.21177583333335, 
0.19282216666668, 0.19371400000002, 0.20586950000001, 0.19327283333335, 
0.19372666666668, 0.20051450000001, 0.20781466666668, 0.19598283333335, 
0.20732916666668, 0.020103833333333, 0.21114316666668, 0.19650250000001, 
0.18752483333335, 0.21125583333335, 0.19664900000001, 0.21818750000001, 
0.17821083333335, 0.20948416666668, 0.20721433333335, 0.20540583333335, 
0.20629083333335, 0.20902950000001, 0.21750033333335, 0.20651450000001, 
0.20718883333334, 0.21365966666668, 0.20680933333335, 0.22068150000001, 
0.20709116666668, 0.20689333333334, 0.0119045, 0.032435333333334, 
0.20285100000001, 0.21743550000001, 0.22040166666668, 0.24638300000001, 
0.21782983333335, 0.20734900000001, 0.22580283333335, 0.22259000000001, 
0.23142700000001, 0.22352366666668, 0.028146500000001, 0.21256266666668, 
0.23776600000001, 0.22164083333334, 0.23566900000001, 0.21526700000001, 
0.22345883333335, 0.20963683333335, 0.22514983333334, 0.22524533333335, 
0.039541500000002, 0.037031333333336, 0.043782000000006, 0.033356500000002, 
0.03685366666667, 0.043621333333337, 0.035313500000002, 0.038210000000001, 
0.051489166666675, 0.052005500000007, 0.041199000000004, 0.059657166666674, 
0.050576166666672, 0.050502666666674, 0.055987166666672, 0.059480333333342, 
0.0076246666666666, 0.066490166666678, 0.060584833333342, 0.050252666666673, 
0.055295000000007, 0.053038833333339, 0.050282333333338, 0.06118050000001, 
0.049213500000006, 0.049903666666673, 0.065745666666674, 0.072357666666678, 
0.084486166666677, 0.079462166666678, 0.071810166666677, 0.07095450000001, 
0.073601833333345, 0.070025000000011, 0.083813000000011, 0.069714500000007, 
0.058678166666677, 0.0082504999999998, 0.086450833333346, 0.094949000000014, 
0.087021666666679, 0.080326166666678, 0.064694666666677, 0.085361000000009, 
0.088569000000012, 0.070275666666679, 0.097831000000012, 0.0126425, 
0.10063966666668, 0.097923500000011, 0.097023166666682, 0.083266000000013, 
0.10554366666668, 0.10320166666668, 0.085690000000011, 0.085126000000013, 
0.089893333333347, 0.11618900000001, 0.11361100000002, 0.11659066666668, 
0.10757750000001, 0.10079066666668, 0.11116733333335, 0.12826450000001, 
0.11668200000001, 0.09820616666668, 0.10874683333335, 0.11157950000002, 
0.0083629999999998, 0.12498183333335, 0.11042733333335, 0.11068433333335, 
0.12639783333335, 0.12013750000001, 0.10502116666668, 0.11037266666668, 
0.13506800000002, 0.11459516666668), type = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), direction = c("downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", 
"downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "downlink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink", 
"uplink", "uplink", "uplink", "uplink")), .Names = c("clusteringDistance", 
"value", "type", "direction"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 
119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 
141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 
152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 
163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 
174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 
185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 
196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 
207L, 208L, 209L, 1515L, 1516L, 1517L, 1518L, 1519L, 1520L, 1521L, 
1522L, 1523L, 1524L, 1525L, 1526L, 1527L, 1528L, 1529L, 1530L, 
1531L, 1532L, 1533L, 1534L, 1535L, 1536L, 1537L, 1538L, 1539L, 
1540L, 1541L, 1542L, 1543L, 1544L, 1545L, 1546L, 1547L, 1548L, 
1549L, 1550L, 1551L, 1552L, 1553L, 1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1557L, 
1558L, 1559L, 1560L, 1561L, 1562L, 1563L, 1564L, 1565L, 1566L, 
1567L, 1568L, 1569L, 1570L, 1571L, 1572L, 1573L, 1574L, 1575L, 
1576L, 1577L, 1578L, 1579L, 1580L, 1581L, 1582L, 1583L, 1584L, 
1585L, 1586L, 1587L, 1588L, 1589L, 1590L, 1591L, 1592L, 1593L, 
1594L, 1595L, 1596L, 1597L, 1598L, 1599L, 1600L, 1601L, 1602L, 
1603L, 1604L, 1605L, 1606L, 1607L, 1608L, 1609L, 1610L, 1611L, 
1612L, 1613L, 1614L, 1615L, 1616L, 1617L, 1618L, 1619L, 1620L, 
1621L, 1622L, 1623L, 1624L, 1625L, 1626L, 1627L, 1628L, 1629L, 
1630L, 1631L, 1632L, 1633L, 1634L, 1635L, 1636L, 1637L, 1638L, 
1639L, 1640L, 1641L, 1642L, 1643L, 1644L, 1645L, 1646L, 1647L, 
1648L, 1649L, 1650L, 1651L, 1652L, 1653L, 1654L, 1655L, 1656L, 
1657L, 1658L, 1659L, 1660L, 1661L, 1662L, 1663L, 1664L, 1665L, 
1666L, 1667L, 1668L, 1669L, 1670L, 1671L, 1672L, 1673L, 1674L, 
1675L, 1676L, 1677L, 1678L, 1679L, 1680L, 1681L, 1682L, 1683L, 
1684L, 1685L, 1686L, 1687L, 1688L, 1689L, 1690L, 1691L, 1692L, 
1693L, 1694L, 1695L, 1696L, 1697L, 1698L, 1699L, 1700L, 1701L, 
1702L, 1703L, 1704L, 1705L, 1706L, 1707L, 1708L, 1709L, 1710L, 
1711L, 1712L, 1713L, 1714L, 1715L, 1716L, 1717L, 1718L, 1719L, 
1720L, 1721L, 1722L, 1723L), class = "data.frame")
```

**ggcommand**

```
ggplot(mod, aes(x=as.factor(clusteringDistance), y=(value) ,   fill=as.factor(type)  )   ) + 
  stat_summary( fun.y=mean, geom="bar", width=0.8, position=position_dodge(width = 0.90) ) +
  facet_grid(direction ~ ., scales="free_y")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the `y-axis` by 10% like this:

```
scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .1)))
```