# How do I generate a histogram for each column of my table?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table of data with a column representing a lab value for each study subject (rows).

I want to generate a series of histograms showing the distribution of values for each lab test (i.e. column). Each set of lab values would ideally have a different bin width (some are integers with a range of hundreds, some are numeric with a range of 2-3).

How do I do that?

Comment: I just came across the [multi.hist() function from the psych package](https://www.personality-project.org/r/html/multi.hist.html) . It allows you to quickly plot histograms by specific columns and looks like you can set different breaks for each column.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you combine the `tidyr` and `ggplot2` packages, you can use `facet_wrap` to make a quick set of histograms of each variable in your data.frame.

You need to reshape your data to long form with `tidyr::gather`, so you have `key` and `value` columns like such:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
# or `library(tidyverse)`

mtcars %>% gather() %>% head()
#>   key value
#> 1 mpg  21.0
#> 2 mpg  21.0
#> 3 mpg  22.8
#> 4 mpg  21.4
#> 5 mpg  18.7
#> 6 mpg  18.1
```

Using this as our data, we can map `value` as our x variable, and use `facet_wrap` to separate by the `key` column:

```r
ggplot(gather(mtcars), aes(value)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins = 10) + 
    facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

The `scales = 'free_x'` is necessary unless your data is all of a similar scale.

You can replace `bins = 10` with anything that evaluates to a number, which may allow you to set them somewhat individually with some creativity. Alternatively, you can set `binwidth`, which may be more practical, depending on what your data looks like. Regardless, binning will take some finesse.

Comment: [Here's an approach for setting different binwidths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17286264/4497050), though it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I was really misunderstanding how the faceting worked. I'll work with the bitwidths article you posted, as they are so different between the values. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

You could generate the plots in a for loop with something like this, if your data frame is named "df" and you want to generate histograms starting with column 2 (if column 1 is your id):

```
for (col in 2:ncol(df)) {
    hist(df[,col])
}
```

The hist function automatically calculates a reasonable bin width, or you can specify a fixed number of bins for all histograms, by adding the breaks argument:

```
hist(df[,col], breaks=10)
```

If you use RStudio, all your plots will be automatically be saved in the plots pane. If not, you will need to save each plot to a separate file inside the loop, as explained here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/

Comment: That is great, thank you. The automatic plot saving is a great addition to my understanding.

Comment: You could add `par(mfrow = c(x, y))` to display them in one plot. Or perhaps make the code wait somehow so that user has the time to look at the plot and proceed to next. Or perhaps add a sleep timer to display each image for a predefined time period. Or, just use something akin to what @alistaire did. :)

Comment: I suggest adding `main = names(df[col])` as an additional argument to the hist function.  It'll label each histogram with the name of the column in question.