# How can I plot histograms of all variables but color by one

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot histograms of all the variables in my dataframe, but I want to color (or fill) the plots by one of the variables. How can I do that?

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372365/how-do-i-generate-a-histogram-for-each-column-of-my-table) shows how to plot histograms for all variables, but not how to color them by one. Conversely, I can plot a histogram for one variable and color it with the code below, but then I have to plot one by one.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, color=factor(vs))) + geom_histogram()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to color all the `facets` based on one of the columns, this is what you are looking for:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(gather(mtcars, key, value, -c(vs)), aes(value, fill=factor(vs))) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) + 
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

If you want to have a different color for each `facet` based on `key` this works:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(gather(mtcars), aes(value, fill=key)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) + 
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm trying to color each histogram by key. For example, in the single histogram plot in my question, `mpg` is colored by `factor(vs)`.

Comment: @GauravBansal so you don't want to have all the column then. You want histogram of all the columns except `vs` and you want to color them by `vs`, right?