# R ggplot2: How to generate a histogram for each column and color by group?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to generate a facet plot of histograms of all variables, but each histograms should be colored by a group. For example, using `mtcars`, I want to get a facet plot of histograms of all variables colored by `am`. I can create a single colored histogram as shown below:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha=0.6, position="identity")
```

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372365/how-do-i-generate-a-histogram-for-each-column-of-my-table/35373419) how to get a facet plot of histograms, but these aren't colored. How can I do both?

Comment: Usually, whenever I hear *"plot something by-column in `ggplot2`"*, my first reaction is to convert the data from "wide to long", where column-name is stored in one column, and column-value is stored in another ... and then facet on the column-name (as @kath's answer does). This is not always right, however, as it combines all values into one column, coercing all contents into one class (integer, numeric, or character). At best, this means your logicals are shown as 0 and 1, but if any of your values are categorical, there-be-problems.

Comment: (If you have categorical data in *one or more* of the columns, you would likely have to resort to two different `gather`s, then `*_join` them together where you'd have `num_value` column from the numeric columns, `disc_value` from the categorical columns, and each would be `NA` for the other (i.e., `all(xor(is.na(num_value),is.na(disc_value)))` is true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gather the data.frame without the variable you'd like to color by.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

ggplot(gather(mtcars, key, value, -am), aes(value, fill = factor(am))) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), alpha = 0.6, position = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]