# How can I specify the bin width for just one histogram?

Tags: r, histogram, ggally

How can I specify the bin width for just one histogram?

```
library(GGally)
data(tips, package="reshape")

library(ggplot2)
ggpairs(data=tips, # data.frame with variables
        columns=1:3, # columns to plot, default to all.
        title="tips data", # title of the plot
        mapping=aes(color=sex)) # aesthetics, ggplot2 style
```

[image]

Comment: the easiest way is to change the ggmatrix. ie `gg <- ggpairs(...`, then `gg[3,1] <- gg[3,1] + geom_histogram( binwidth = 50) ; gg`

Comment: if you are only wanting to change it in one facet, then overwrite that cell along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271968/different-breaks-per-facet-in-ggplot2-histogram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@user2957945 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508920/how-can-i-specify-the-bin-width-for-just-one-histogram#comment66334413_39508920):

```
library(GGally)
data(tips, package="reshape")

library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggpairs(data=tips, # data.frame with variables
        columns=1:3, # columns to plot, default to all.
        title="tips data", # title of the plot
        mapping=aes(color=sex)) # aesthetics, ggplot2 style
gg[3,1] <- gg[3,1] + geom_histogram( binwidth = 50)
gg
```