# R - Histograms with shared/same x and y axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to plot two histograms where the x and y ranges are the same for both. After reading some posts, my solution is to use ggplot2, geom_histogram twice. The first time I am creating the plots without plotting for each dataset of interest with the intention to get the maximum y/count and x axes values among all plots of interest. For example, having two plots, if for the first one ymax_1 = 10 for the other ymax_2 = 15, then both plots will have a y axis range from 0 to 15 at least. Similarly holds for the x axis.

After this plot, I take the ymax/xmax values and plot the histograms like before with the addition of xlim( 0, xmax) and ylim( 0, ymax). However, when I do this, the amount of counts changes. More specifically, in the first plots where I don't have any xlim/ylim specified I get from ggplot_build( ggplot(...) + geom_histogram(...)) ymax = 2000 but when I use xlim the second time I get ymax = 4000. Nevertheless, from the 1st plot I have ymax = 2000 and hence the second time the histograms are not plotted properly. When I remove the xlim option I get the same result.

How and why the xlim option affects the amount of counts? I hope that was clear.

```
df = read.table( paste( path, f, sep = "/"), header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
measure = colnames( df)[ 7]
combs = unique( df[, c( 'A', 'B', 'C')])
# order combs in specific order to get a specific sequence of plots
combs = combs[ with( combs, order( B, C, A)), ]
bns = lst()
xmxs = lst()
ymxs = lst()
for( j in seq( 1, length( combs[ , 1]), 2)) {
 if( combs[ j, 2] == combs[ j, 3]) {
  next
 }
 tmp = subset( df, A == combs[ j, 1] & B == combs[ j, 2] & C == combs[ j, 3], select = c( measure))
 # Freedman – Diaconis rule, "On the histogram as a density estimator: L2 theory"
 bw = 2 * IQR( tmp[ , 1]) / ( length( tmp[ , 1])^(1/3))
 bns[[ j]] = ceiling( ( max( tmp[ , 1]) - min( tmp[ , 1])) / bw)

 plots[[ j]] = ggplot( tmp, aes_string( measure)) + geom_histogram( bins = bns[[ j]], aes( fill = ..count..))
 histg = ggplot_build( plots[[ j]])$data[[ 1]]
 ymxs[[ j]] = max( histg$count)
 xmxs[[ j]] = max( histg$x)

 tmp = subset( df, A == combs[ j + 1, 1] & B == combs[ j + 1, 2] & C == combs[ j + 1, 3], select = c( measure))
 # Freedman – Diaconis rule, "On the histogram as a density estimator: L2 theory"
 bw = 2 * IQR( tmp[ , 1]) / ( length( tmp[ , 1])^(1/3))
 bns[[ j + 1]] = ceiling( ( max( tmp[ , 1]) - min( tmp[ , 1])) / bw)

 plots[[ j + 1]] = ggplot( tmp, aes_string( measure)) + geom_histogram( bins = bns[[ j + 1]], aes( fill = ..count..))
 histg = ggplot_build( plots[[ j + 1]])$data[[ 1]]
 ymxs[[ j + 1]] = max( histg$count)
 xmxs[[ j + 1]] = max( histg$x)
 if( ymxs[[ j]] > ymxs[[ j + 1]]) {
  ymxs[[ j + 1]] = ymxs[[ j]]
 }
 else {
  ymxs[[ j]] = ymxs[[ j + 1]]
 }
 if( xmxs[[ j]] > xmxs[[ j + 1]]) {
  xmxs[[ j + 1]] = xmxs[[ j]]
 }
 else {
  xmxs[[ j]] = xmxs[[ j + 1]]
 }
}
pplots = lst()
for( j in 1 : length( combs[ , 1])) {
 if( combs[ j, 2] == combs[ j, 3]) {
  next
 }
 tmp = subset( df, A == combs[ j, 1] & B == combs[ j, 2] & C == combs[ j, 3], select = c( measure))
 avg = sprintf( "%.2f", mean( tmp[ , 1]))
 stdv = sprintf( "%.2f", std( tmp[ , 1]))
 count = length( tmp[ , 1])
 entities[[ j]] = paste( combs[ j, 1], " ", combs[ j, 2], " vs ", combs[ j, 3])
pplots[[ j]] = ggplot( tmp, aes_string( measure)) +
 geom_histogram( bins = bns[[ j]], aes( fill = ..count..)) +
 # xlim( 0, 1.2*xmxs[[ j]]) +
 # ylim( 0, 1.2*ymxs[[ j]]) +
 ggtitle( bquote( atop( paste( .(entities[[ j]])), paste( mu, " = ", .( avg), ", ", sigma, " = ", .( stdv), ", #cells = ", .( count), sep = " ")))) +
 theme( plot.title = element_text( size = 20), axis.text = element_text( size = 12), axis.title = element_text( size = 15))
 }

 # plot every two plots because the Reference.Population is the same
 for( j in seq( 1, length( plots), 2)) {
 fileext = str_remove_all( entities[[ j]], 'N')
 filename_hi = paste( gsub( '.{4}$', '', f), "_distribution_", fileext, ".png", sep = "")
 png( filename = paste( path, filename_hi, sep = "/"))
 grid.draw( rbind( ggplotGrob( pplots[[ j]]), ggplotGrob( pplots[[ j + 1]]), size = "last"))
 dev.off()
 }
```

So, in the code above, `plots` contains the initial plots from which I get the min and max values for y,x axes and `pplots` contains the plots that I plot finally using the `xlim/ylim` options. However, for example,

`max( plots[[ 8]]$data[[ 1]]$count) != max( plots[[ 8]]$data[[ 1]]$count)`

when I use the `xlim` option. The first one gives `1947` and the other one gives `4529` for my data.

Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the other posts you read, I suggest combining the datasets into one, and faceting them. To do that, you need to select the column you want histogrammed, and add a column that indicates the dataset from which the data is extracted.

For this example, I'll combine `iris$Sepal.Length` and `mtcars$disp`.

```r
range(mtcars$disp)
# [1]  71.1 472.0
range(iris$Sepal.Length)
# [1] 4.3 7.9
```

Since these example data are so different, I'll scale one so that plot looks more comparable ... but different enough so that you can see that the axes are shared.

```r
400 * (range(iris$Sepal.Length) - 4)
# [1]  120 1560
```

over to you if you need anything like this for your data.

From here, combine the relevant fields:

```r
combined_dat <- rbind(
  cbind.data.frame(src = "iris Sepal.Length", val = 400 * (iris[, c("Sepal.Length")] - 4)),
  cbind.data.frame(src = "mtcars disp*", val = mtcars[, c("disp")])
)

head(combined_dat)
#                 src val
# 1 iris Sepal.Length 440
# 2 iris Sepal.Length 360
# 3 iris Sepal.Length 280
# 4 iris Sepal.Length 240
# 5 iris Sepal.Length 400
# 6 iris Sepal.Length 560

tail(combined_dat)
#              src   val
# 177 mtcars disp* 120.3
# 178 mtcars disp*  95.1
# 179 mtcars disp* 351.0
# 180 mtcars disp* 145.0
# 181 mtcars disp* 301.0
# 182 mtcars disp* 121.0
```

And then plot.

```r
ggplot(combined_dat, aes(val)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~ src, ncol = 1)
# `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image: combining histograms]

Comment: When using `facet_wrap` how can I pass separate bins/breaks for each plot? Since, the choice of bins affects how the histogram looks like and the consequent conclusions I would prefer to provide an amount of bins that is somehow optimal such as from Freedman – Diaconis rule.

Comment: You can use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271968/different-breaks-per-facet-in-ggplot2-histogram, and see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/rhPWQEFMx6A and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/aQQ2hTYRQF8/discussion.

Comment: Does this answer your question?